# Сравнение изображений с помощью Python

Tags: python, изображения

Есть окно с всплывающими простыми изображениями
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там просто цифры, по одному числу. Координаты мест, где они появляются известны. Можно делать скриншоты по координатам с помощью pyscreenshot. Заготовки этих изображений есть - там просто десять вариантов кругляшей с числами в них. 
Нужно сравнить имеющиеся у меня картинки с этими, где цифры все время разные.

Какой самый простой способ сравнения известных изображений?

Вроде бы opencv слишком мощный для этого?

Смысл кода - прост: выводить в виде функции то, что появляется в виде изображения, т.е. картинка с 1 - a, картинка с 2 - b и так далее.

Comment: Возможно, самый быстрый и простой способ - наложение маски. Я бы использовал OpenCV. Но если время выполнения - не критично, то можно через проверку пикселей.

Comment: Время, конечно, критично. Картинки обновляются. Что значит наложение маски?

Answer (score 1):

**autopy**

Позволяет найти известные заданные изображения в захватах с экрана.
Координаты программа находит сама.
Можно указать точность сравнения изображений.

Примеры операторов

```
import autopy
```

Это для Python2, есть вариант программы и для Python3

```
zamok  =autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open("D:/zamok.bmp")
```

Загрузка изображения, которой будем искать.

```
zast=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
```

Захват экрана.

```
 pos = zast.find_bitmap(zast,0.001)
```

Выдает координаты найденного изображения.

```
rect_vert=(0,0),(100,720)
rect_gor=(0,0),(1200,150)

zast=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen(rect_vert)
```

Ограничивает размер захвата экрана. (Левая, верхняя граница - берет только нули ????)

Ниже пример кода управляющего Компасом по данным захвата экрана.
Программа захватывает экран и ждет окончания редактирования эскиза, затем включает проверку эскиза, анализирует результат проверки и может снова вернуть эскиз в режим редактирования.

Некоторые действия в Компасе трудно реализовать программно и такими средствами можно решить практически все задачи.

```
import autopy
import time
import ctypes
from autopy import mouse


#_________________________________________________________________________
def Poisk(imfile):
    filee=autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open(imfile)
    for n in range(68):
        zast=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
        pos = zast.find_bitmap(filee,0.001)
        if type(pos)==tuple:
            a=1
            break
        else:
            pass
    return pos

#_________________________________________________________________________
def Levoj(x,y,t):
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)
    time.sleep(t)
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0) # left down
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0) # left up
#_________________________________________________________________________
def Pravoj(x,y,t):
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)
    time.sleep(t)
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x08, 0, 0, 0,0) # left down
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x10, 0, 0, 0,0) # left up
#_________________________________________________________________________
def Enter_():
    time.sleep(0.001)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0)         #'??? enter
    time.sleep(0.001)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x0D, 0,0x0002, 0)     #'????????? enter
    time.sleep(0.001)





zamok  =autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open("D:/zamok.bmp")
zamknut=autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open("D:/zamknut.bmp")
net_   =autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open("D:/net_.bmp")
ok   =autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open("D:/ok.bmp")


rect_vert=(0,0),(100,720)
rect_gor=(0,0),(1200,150)

zast=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen(rect_vert)
pos_zamok_pr = zast.find_bitmap(zamok,0.001)

for n in range(1128600):

    zast=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen(rect_vert)
    pos_zamok_sl = zast.find_bitmap(zamok,0.001)


    if type(pos_zamok_pr)==tuple:
        if type(pos_zamok_sl)==tuple:
            pass
        else:
            ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(555,555)
        #    time.sleep(0.2)
            ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x08, 0, 0, 0,0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x10, 0, 0, 0,0)


            pos=Poisk('D:/redaktirovat.bmp')
            time.sleep(0.7)
            Levoj(pos[0]+7, pos[1]+5,0.4)
            time.sleep(0.5)

            zast_gor=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
            pos_zamknut = zast_gor.find_bitmap(zamknut,0.01)

            Levoj(pos_zamknut[0]+7, pos_zamknut[1]+5,0.4)

            for cik in range(11):
                zast=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
                pos_net = zast.find_bitmap(net_,0.001)
                pos_ok = zast.find_bitmap(ok,0.001)
                print ("net",pos_net)
                print ("ok",pos_ok)
                if type(pos_net)==tuple:
                    break
                if type(pos_ok)==tuple:
                    Enter_()

                    Pravoj(368,386,0.4)

                    Levoj(368+22,386+122,0.4)

                    time.sleep(0.1)



    pos_zamok_pr=pos_zamok_sl
```

Answer (score 0):

Считай хеш-суммы картинок (md5, sha). Это самый простой способ. Хеш-сумма будет уникальна для каждой картинки.